# Not able to convert Random to int

Tags: c#, random

I'm new to programming and can't figure this bit of code out and why it wont work like someone says here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55fb3116-c978-4ac8-9381-a2605e16e256/how-do-you-create-a-random-number-in-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Random Random = new Random();
  int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 2);
  // int[] Tal = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  // MessageBox.Show( Tal[1] );
  string[] Names = { "Lasse", "Mads", "Alberte" };
  MessageBox.Show( Names[Random] );
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What behavior are you expecting and how does it differ from the behavior you're getting?

Comment: On line 4 you have `random` but you never create a variable called `random`. On line 3 it looks like you're trying to create a variable called `Random` (capital "R"), which is a bad idea because there's already a class called `Random`. Letter case is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `randomNumber`, not `Random`:

```
MessageBox.Show( Names[randomNumber] );
```

And your `Random` instance should be assigned to `random`, not `Random`:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

C# is case sensitive, so `random` and `Random` are two differents identifiers.

and btw. `Random.Next(0, 2)` gives you only `0`s and `1`s. You should use `Random.Next(0, 3)` to get values between `0` and `2`.

> **Parameters**
>
> *maxValue*
>
> The **exclusive** upper bound of the random number returned. (...)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Im really happy that i can get help with starting to learn programming!
Lasse